# Is there any number $n$ such that $nm=0$, $n\neq 0$, and $m\neq 0$?

Tags: products

I [answered](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-sixth-grade-math/cc-6th-expressions-and-variables/cc-6th-equivalent-expressions/v/combining-like-terms?qa_expand_key=ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJvCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiTHVzZXJfaWRfa2V5X2h0dHA6Ly9ub3VzZXJpZC5raGFuYWNhZGVteS5vcmcvNGZkN2NhMDcxZjEwZDkyODJkMWM5M2NkMzE3ZGVkNjkMCxIIRmVlZGJhY2sYgICAgOS_mQoM) a question about whether zero is prime or composite on Khan Academy a while ago. Since then, two people have commented on my answer, asking another question that I don't know the answer to.

Are there zero divisors (numbers such that, when multiplied by some nonzero number, the product is zero) other than zero? If so, what are they? Wouldn't that go against the Zero Product Property, which states that if you take two numbers, $n$ and $m$, and multiply them together to get zero, then either $n$ or $m$ is equal to zero? I.e. if $nm=0$, then either $n=0$ and $m=0$.

Comment: Depends where: in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ take $n=2,m=3$

Comment: it depends on your ring. in Z, nm=0 means n=0 or m=0.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta What exactly is $Z/6Z$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} / 6\mathbb{Z}$ is the multiplicative group of integers modulo $6$. Read here for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: @YiyuanLee: It is not a group but merely a monoid (there are no zero divisors in a group since they do not have an inverse). The group $(ℤ/6ℤ)^*$ exists, but it does not contain the elements 2 and 3.

Comment: **Note** $\ $ Following the link reveals the context is "6th grade math (US)". So mention of fields and domains is probably over the head of the audience. Maybe they could understand zero-divisors in modular integer arithmetic if suitably explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *fields* (e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{C}$) and *integral domains* (e.g. $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}[x]$), no such pair of "numbers" $n,m$ can exist.

For fields, this follows from the invertibility of multiplication. If $nm = 0$ but $n \neq 0$, then $m = n^{-1}0 = 0$, and vice versa.

For *integral domains*, this is an axiom - and it's *precisely* what differentiates *integral domains* from *rings*.

In arbitrary rings, such numbers *can* exists. E.g., in the ring $\mathbb{Z_4} = \{0,1,2,3\}$ you have $2\cdot 2 = 4 = 0$.

Comment: Better to use *integral* domain (domain of integrity is very old-fashioned and little-used nowadays).

Comment: @BillDubuque Fixed. I keep making that mistake - probably because the german word is "Integritätsbereich", which literally translates to "integrity domain". Oh well...

Comment: @fgp: Is it really valid to say 4 = 0 directly? Is there not something more to it.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45945/242) on the etymology of "integral domain".

Comment: @Nick It's absolutely valid, and there's really nothing more to it; in $\mathbb{Z}_/4\mathbb{Z}$, $4$ and $0$ are different names for the same element.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by a "number".  Are we talking about real numbers? Complex numbers?  Split-complex?  Quaternions?  Octonions?  Arbitrary rings?

Certainly, if we state that $n$ and $m$ are real numbers, then this statement must hold.