# What does the "integral" in Integral domain stand for?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

This will be an odd question, but... In the name [Integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain), what is the meaning of word integral? Does it refer to integral such as adjective for noun *integer*? Or does it instead refer to noun *integrity*?

The reason I am asking... In Czech language this is translated (when I would translate it back literally) as a "*Domain of integrity*" ("*[Obor integrity](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obor_integrity)*" for czechs here). But I suspect the original meaning was perhaps intended to refer to integers, instead of integrity? Just wondering if the translation is perhaps inaccurate...

As pointed out in comments, this question might have answer to this [where does the term "integral domain" come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45945/where-does-the-term-integral-domain-come-from), I just don't see what the answer is (it seems both the terms are referred there...)

Comment: It is "integrity" in Spanish, too.

Comment: In German aswell.

Comment: I always thought it was named after the integers, because of the lack of zero divisors in the integers. But, since the ring of integers is also a UFD/PID/Euclidean Domain, I suppose it doesn't make all that much sense to name Integral Domains after them.

Comment: @ZainPatel Thanks for the reference, it seems it should contain the answer, but I seem to be unable to get it from there...

Comment: "Integral domain" is merely the translation of German "Integralbereich".  Which does not answer your question, but suggest looking in the German-language literature from 100 years ago for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was given to believe, probably by reading Wikipedia or some such thing, that it's a reference to the integers, which provide the most familiar example of this phenomenon.   Indeed,  in $\mathbb Z$ there are no divisors of zero.   That is, $ab=0\implies a=0\lor b=0$.