# Definitions of a Factor Surrounding $0 | 0$

Tags: notation, definition

As far as I can tell, there seems to be some controversy surrounding whether $0 | 0$. Is this partly due to different definitions of what it means for, say, $a$ to be a factor of $b$?

**[Def 1]:** $\forall a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a | b \iff \exists c\in\mathbb{Z}\;(b = ca)$.

- This would allow $0|0$ since $0 = 0 \cdot 0$.

**[Def 2]:** $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a | b \iff {b \over a} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

- This would not allow $0|0$ since ${0 \over 0} \not \in \mathbb{Z}.$

So which is the most common definition of a factor? I would like to know whether I can or should use $0|0$ in a slightly unrelated proof.

Comment: I would usually take the first definition to be better, but whether or not you can use it depends on what definition is being used in the rest of the proof (although the condition should be written $\forall a,b\in \mathbb Z\,\exists c\in \mathbb Z,\,a|b\,\Longleftrightarrow\,b=ca$. Your first definition is currently not right)

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ Definition 1 implies definition 2. Thus in a way you can say definition 1 is a more general definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would some elementary number theory notes exclude 0|0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666103/why-would-some-elementary-number-theory-notes-exclude-00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In number theory, the first of your definitions is practically universal (though $c$ should be existentially quantified, as noted by Milo Brandt in a comment).

It implies that $a\mid a$ for all $a$, that everything divides $0$, and that $a\mid b$ exactly if $\langle b\rangle\subseteq \langle a\rangle$ (as an inclusion between principal ideals of $\mathbb Z$).

Also, once you accept $a\mid 0$ for nonzero $a$, it is necessary that $0\mid 0$, or divisibility would not be a partial order.

Answer (score 1):

Definition 2 goes into the idea that $\mathbb{Z}$ somehow admits division but is not a group, so is not probably a good idea.

Definition 1 should read:

$$\forall a,b \in\mathbb{R} a | b \iff \exists c\in\mathbb{Z}\;(b = ca), \text{with c unique}$$

Which as we have $0=c\cdot0$ as true, $c$ is not unique.

Comment: Do you mean "Definition 2 should read"? Your added uniqueness requirement would prevent $0$ from dividing itself.

Comment: i was going for the assumption that division is well-defined over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes, but that would still be for definition 2, right? Definition 1 is not based on division at all.