# Definition of integer division in Dummit and Foote

Tags: divisibility, integers

Dummit and Foote says the following about integer division.

> If $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \neq 0$, we say $a$ divides $b$ if there is an element $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = ac$. In this case we write $a \mid b$; if $a$ does not divide $b$, we write $a \not \mid b$.

My question, though perhaps a bit silly, is why we require that $a \neq 0$. If $a = 0$, then the only possible value of $b$ would be $0$. We could then pick any value of $c$.

Is it correct that say that $a = 0$ divides $b = 0$? Is there another reason we exclude $a = 0$?

Comment: Might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666103/why-would-some-elementary-number-theory-notes-exclude-00

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Definition)

Comment: This is just one way to define divisibility. Although yes, using the definition: "for $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ we say that $a \mid b$ if and only if there exists $c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $b = ac$", then $0 \mid 0$.

Comment: Personally, I find it nice to allow $a=0$. It lets me think of the "divides" relation as another ordering on (all of) the integers, with zero being the largest element, and one being the smallest.

Comment: Most definitions I've seen require that $a$ be nonzero. If I had to take a stab at why, it's because the division algorithm gives a *unique* $c$ such that $b=ac$, and if $a=0$, then $c$ can be any real number.