# For all $d\in \mathbb N$ exists two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is maybe a stupid question but I have to ask,

> Is it correct that for all $d\in \mathbb N$ exists two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=d$?

I think that the answer is **NO** e.g let's take $d=0$

> Am I correct?

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: Yes it is, why not?

Comment: @Error404 : Ok, Is it true for non zero natural numbers?

Comment: For non zero I think that the answer will be **Yes**

Comment: how? @Error404....

Comment: Some authors will assume $\mathbb{N}$ not to include $0$, so it's best to make this explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct if $0 \in \Bbb N$ For all other numbers, there are.

Comment: Depending on how we define $\gcd$. Some definitions make $\gcd(0,0)=0$.

Comment: And with good reason, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495119/what-is-gcd0-0.