# gcd of $f(x)$ and 0 polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, polynomial-rings

When the integer case,

$ \gcd (a, 0 ) = a$ for $a( \neq 0)  \in  \mathbb Z$

Plus people generally said  $\gcd(0,0)$ can't be defined.

Then...

When we expand this consideration by the polynomials ring $F[x]$ for a field, $F$

What about the case $\gcd(f(x), 0)$ ? (Here the $f  (\neq 0)  \in F[x]$, $0$ is $0$ a polynomial in $F[x]$)

plus Could I regard  the case   $\gcd(0,0)$ Can't be defined like the integer case?

Comment: Yea, it's the same thing. I've seen some people define $\gcd(0,0)$ as $0$, implictly viewing $0$ as a divisor larger than any other divisor. But it's a weird construction that doesn't really offer much computational advantage, so most mathematicians don't do that.

Comment: @Don $d\mid f,0\iff d\mid f\ $ holds even when $\,f=0.\ $ More generally note  $\gcd(f,g) = f\,$ when $\,f\mid g\,$ since then: $\ \ d\mid f,g\iff d\mid f\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, the expression you've written isn't rendering for me/

Comment: @Don Alternatively $\,\gcd(f,g) = f\gcd(1,f/g) = f.\ $ It renders fine here.

Comment: That only works when $f\neq0$, no?

Comment: @Don The first proof works when $\,f = 0.\ $ For the 2nd one, if $\,f = 0\,$ then $\,f\mid g\,\Rightarrow\, g=0\,$ so it's true as above, else we proceed as in the prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque Your expression is again, not rendering for me.

Comment: @Don All render fine in all my browsers, so it's likely a problem on your end. You can click on the expressions to see the MathJax.

Comment: @BillDubuque I've been trying to click on them to see the MathJax, but it's not letting me.

Comment: @Don I notices some strange renderings earlier today so there may be a global problem.

Comment: @Don Also reported on [Meta yesterday.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30861/242) are you using a Chromium based browser?

Comment: @BillDubuque Just using Chrome. I'm not particularly adept at technology.

Comment: Typo alert: Should be $\,g/f\,$ not $\,f/g\,$ above

Comment: Related: [What is $\gcd(0,0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/495119)