# Relation between ideal numbers and ideals of a ring?

Tags: ideals

I would like to know whether the ideal numbers of Kummer (or the ideals of Dedekind for that matter) are closely related to the concept of ideal (right ideal, left ideal, two-sided ideal and so on.....) in a ring. If so, in which manner? Or are they eventually the same thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some reference or definition for these concepts?

Comment: you find a reference, for instance, in Kolmogorov's encyclopaedia

Comment: Do you have a reference that one can easily find?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29

Comment: Does [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/63918) shed light?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer.It does shed light with regard to the specifics of Kummer's invention and Dedekind's development thereafter. However, what I want to know is the relation between that and the definition of Ideal, Right-Ideal and so on in Ring Theory as it is known today. It wold also be nice to know who set that relation as well......