# History of Commutative Algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, math-history

There are books on the history of Algebraic Geometry, there are also papers about it (all had done by J. Dieudonné). But I could not find any book or paper about the history of Commutative Algebra. When I studied a topic, I would like to study its history to get a more global view. Please suggest me the papers or books about the history of Commutative Algebra.
Thank for reading :)

Comment: The first chapter of Eisenbud's _Commutative Algebra_ gives a brief history of the subject, showing how it arose from number-theoretic and geometric considerations.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61497/

Comment: For a somewhat raw snippet of history you can read Zariski's introductory comments to his collected works; he discusses various results in commutative algebra that were known around 1930 (in particular, Krull's work) and then describes how he built on those results in his work on algebraic geometry.  (Zariski was also one of the great commutative algebraists, proving many fundamental results, always with their geometric applications in mind.)

Comment: Thank you very much Matt E. But how can I find those paper? Could you please post the concrete names of them ?

Comment: @Nguyen: Dear Nguyen, Zariski's collected works were published in four volumes; the comments I have in mind are at the beginning of the first or second volume, I think.  If you have access to a good university library, you will be able to find them in it.  Regards,

Comment: Why don't you read the historical notes at the end of Bourbaki's volume on Commutative Algebra?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The history of commutative algebra is mixed with the history of algebraic number theory and the history of algebraic geometry. It is actually mixed into the history of the ring concept as well, motivated by these applications. See

- [History of the Concept of a Ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362/history-of-the-concept-of-a-ring)
- [Episodes in the History of Modern Algebra (1800-1950)](http://bookstore.ams.org/hmath-32/)
- [A History of Abstract Algebra](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/historyofscience/book/978-0-8176-4684-4)
- [On the early history of commutative algebra with special emphasis on divisibility theories and the foundations of algebraic geometry](https://archive.org/details/lecture_10193)

Comment: Thank you very much lhf. Your links work well. Today, my friend told me that Huneke also wrote a paper about Commutative Algebra and related maths subject. If ones know it, please send me its informations. Thanks and I beg your pardon for my poor English

Comment: Really appreciated this answer. The last link is now broken, but it refers to a lecture that can still be found on the Internet Archive. See the following link: https://archive.org/details/lecture_10193

(I've also submitted an edit to the above answer to incorporate such link directly...)